Code and compile C when the office blocks Visual studio
Hi there I'm an amateur / beginner coder and occasionally do some C coding in office at lunch break.
Unfortunately they're now blocking visual studio (probably through the firewall) - is there any other editor/compiler/coding environment I can use instead that does not require any install?
Charles.
I tried a few standalone tools that I found pretty crappy. I tried some apps on iPhone but realized it's not realistic either.

Any text editor and command line compiler will do. Thera are also IDEs other than Visual studio, such as VSCode, Eclipse, Code::Blocks. There are also web based tools, such as IDEone, Godbolt, OnlineGDB.

I suggest you use an online compiler such as Programiz or OnlineGDB for your experimentation, unless these also are blocked by your firewall. It means not needing to install anything, and you can do everything from editing and compiling through to testing, with minimal effort.
Just remember to save your programs locally, if you want to keep them for later, after you've closed your editor tabs or Microsoft has seen fit to reboot your machine for you.

You can use Online IDEs like Replit to run, compile and store your C code online.
There are online compilers like Programiz out there but if you want to store the code that you've worked on and want to keep it organised or if you have multiple C files that need to work together then Replit is the right choice.
